# How to Fix Computer internet Connection?

Tags: windows-7, networking, internet, internet-connection

I just Freshly installed Windows 7, and It says i am connected to the internet through the Ethernet port, and it says It is a good connection, but whenever I go onto IE and try to load a website it just sits the and the loading bard says, "Waiting for www.websitename.com" And it just sits there like that doing nothing. I also tried using a wireless connection, and it still does the same thing. I know it's not the router because all the other computers that are connected are working fine. I also Tried reseting the netsh winsock, and the other ip stuff, but that still didn't work. I can Also Ping a website in Cmd, and it works. Any help would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like DNS resolution problems...

Try setting different DNS server(s) in the network properties (say [8.8.8.8](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using)), and check into the [NSLookup](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/200525) utility in Windows for diagnosing.

Comment: I tried NsLookup, and it says, "Server: unknown" But it shows the default gateway adress, but below that it says DNS request timed out. And I tried setting the Dns Server to 8.8.8.8 but that didn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1. Open IE
2. Settings -> Internet options -> Advanced -> Reset...
3. Check (Delete personal settings)
4. Reset
5. Close IE
6. Reset your laptop
7. Open IE

If this doesn't work, please update the question with more details about your network adapter settings.

Comment: I actually just Tried a wireless connection again, and It works using the wireless connection, but for some reason he Lan doesn't work. Its a desktop too. So maybe the onboard Ethernet Adapter is not working correctly? I also just tried a Pci Ethernet card, and it doesn't connect, and tells me that, "Local Area connection 1 doesn't have a valid Ip configuration" Even after Diagnosing it, it tells me to reset the router, or it tells me that it can't fix the problem.

Comment: Can you give us a screenshot or more into on your "Local Area Connection" network adapter settings?